# How to extend elastic search response by adding field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get a similarity metric between search term and results within the elastic search response.

For example: when user made a search with the term such as "john", this similarity metric should return a value for a result "john.doe" between 0 and 1.

Should I need to develop a plugin for creating a new rest handler, or is there another way to intercept `_search` call and insert additional field to the response?

Comment: How are you calculating similarity? Elastic search outputs score of documents in response

Comment: there's no such thing as a normalised score between two set numbers in Elasticsearch (ie 0 and 1), all scores are relevant to other docs in the query. if you wanted to do this it'd be custom development outside of Elasticsearch

Comment: @jaspreetchahal I am planning to calculate similarity score with levensthein distance. It will be an additional field for indicating the pure similarity, independent from other docs.